# Lambda parameters and Visual Studio 2008 autocompletion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

When calling methods with a signature that has a delegate, using lamba syntax, Visual Studio 2008 replaces my arbitrary parameter names with autocompleted names.

```
private void parseIntCell(DataGridViewCell focusCell, Action<Receipt_Detail, int> recorder)
```

As I type the following:

```
parseDecimalCell(focusCell, 2, ((x,
```

As soon as I type the comma, Visual Studio turns it into

```
parseDecimalCell(focusCell, 2, ((XmlReadMode,
```

What I wanted to ultimately type

```
parseDecimalCell(focusCell, 2, ((x,y) => x.Grower_Box_Weight = y));
```

Is there any way to configure my code or Visual Studio so I can enter these types of lambas without having to press esc to undo the autocomplete, while still having autocomplete for normal code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing CTRL+Alt+Space together, this will not disable autocomplete but in order to autocomplete you need to select from the list.

Comment: This toggles the completion mode in Intellisense (its under the menu Edit -> Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode in VS2019) and is a really useful option to reduce stress in most places but didn't seem to help in stopping VS autowrecking lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than enclosing your lambda expression in parentheses, you could enclose the body of your lambda's function in braces, like so:

```
private void doSomethingWithADelegate(Action<int, int> myFunc)
{
    // ...
}

void Foo()
{
    int a = 0;
    doSomethingWithADelegate((x, y) => { a = a + x + y; });
}
```

When I use this syntax, Intellisense doesn't try to make any changes after typing "(x,".

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused by this answer. Isn't "(x, " typed before there are braces?